# Mashup band names recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to mashup some band names, this is supposed to be down recursively, where I remove a key from the original data structure and add it to the new one.

If you run this code, you will see a problem immediately, but I can't figure out what's causing it:

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

var bands = {

    "1": 'stone temple pilots',
    "2": 'alice in chains',
    "3": 'fats domino',
    "4": 'A Box of Fish with Tartar Sauce',
    "5": 'Barthalomu Cubbins',
    "6": 'Third World',
    "7": 'Third Eye Blind',
    "8": 'Alcoholocaust'

};

var newBands = {

};

var seed = Math.floor(Math.random()*(Object.size(bands)-1));

console.log(seed);

var next;
var str;

function getOther(number){

    if(Object.size(bands) > 0){

        str = String(number);

        newBands[str] = bands[str];
        console.log(newBands[str]);
        delete bands[str];
        console.log(Object.size(bands));
        next = Math.floor(Math.random()*(Object.size(bands)-1));
        getOther(next);
    }
}


getOther(seed);
```

Comment: WARNING: "If you run this code, you will see a problem immediately" - this is an infinite loop, it will crash your tab. Do not do this. OP, shame on you; this is not what you do in a question. Now stop being lazy and describe what happens.

Comment: well, I don't know why I am getting an infinite loop!

Comment: That's fine, and I'm about to answer that. But it is incredibly rude not to tell people "This is getting into an infinite loop, why?" instead of "Try this, you'll see what's wrong". Would you go to a doctor's office, cough into his mouth and say "so, guess what I have"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number` will be between `0` and `N-2`, where `N` is number of remaining bands. You then remove band with that number, *without renumbering the others*. After a couple of iterations, you will be left with only high numbers; maybe `5, 6, 7, 8`, maybe even just `6, 7, 8`, when `number` can only be between `0` and `2` or `3`. Whichever number gets picked, there is no element under that number, nothing gets removed, the object does not shrink, the recursion plunges on.

It would be so much better to use an array and `splice`. If you really want to use an object, then don't use `bands[number]`, but `bands[Object.keys(bands)[number]]`. (Also, the conversion to string is completely unnecessary.) Also,

```
number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.size(bands));
```

without `-1`.

EDIT: Also, your `Object.size(obj)` can be replaced by `Object.keys(obj).length`.